# How to start afresh with a new database in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I deleted my database. I want to start afresh with a new database. How can I do that ? I tried making a new datasource but it gives me an error while applying migrations/or migrating that it couldn't find the tables? Which is true because its an empty database.

A similar scenario would be when some one pulls a version of my code. He wouldn't have migrations or the database (untracked). How would he run the application?

Comment: You have to run the migration which you should deliver with your code.

Comment: I have not been tracking the migrations folder or the database with version control. How can initialize the db now ?

Comment: Then you have to create a new initial migration.

Answer (score 5):

Delete all the folders named 'migrations'. And go to terminal and run `./manage.py makemigrations`, `./manage.py migrate --run-syncdb`.

Comment: Do not remove the whole folders, and keep the `__init__.py` files. Otherwise you'll have issues when trying to create the tables with `makemigrations` and `migrate` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391330/relation-does-not-exist-error-in-django)